# Using TDD to develop file traversing code in Java

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, tdd

I had to implement some code to traverse a directory structure and return a list of files found. The requirements were pretty simple:

1. Given a base directory, find all files (which are not directories themselves) within.
2. If a directory is found, repeat step 1 for it.

I wanted to develop the code using TDD. As I started writing the tests, I realized that I was mocking class `File`, so I could intercept calls to `File.isDirectory()` and so on. In this way, I was forcing myself to use a solution where I would call that method.

I didn't like it because this test is definitely tightly coupled to the implementation. If I ever change the way in which I ask if a file is a directory, then this test is going to fail even if I keep the contract working. Looking at it as a [Private Unit Test](http://theholyjava.wordpress.com/2011/10/20/never-mix-public-and-private-unit-tests/) made me feel uneasy, for all the reasons expressed on that post. I'm not sure if this is one of those cases where I need to use that kind of testing. On the other hand, I really want to be sure that it returns every file that its not also a directory, traversing the entire structure. To me, that requires a nice, simple, test.

I wanted to avoid having to create a testing directory structure with real testing files "on disk", as I saw it rather clumsy and against some of the best practices that I have read.

Bear in mind that I don't need to do anything with the contents, so tricks like using `StringReader` instead of `FileReader` do not apply here. I thought I could do something equivalent, though, like being able to create a directory structure in memory when I set up the test, then tearing it down. I haven't found a way to do it.

How would you develop this code using TDD?

Thanks!

Comment: One option is [Commons VFS](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-vfs/index.html) but usually I just use "real" file access and have my tests use a special directory for testing.

Comment: @DavidWallace you should put that as an answer.

Comment: Thanks @DavidWallace! I guess that Commons VFS might be an overkill for my purposes. Having a "real" file structure simplifies the test and makes it much less coupled to the implementation. I'll try that!

Comment: Yes, I've found that using real files works well.  There are a few gotchas though.  You really want to give each test method its own subdirectory, to remove the possibility of tests interacting with each other.  And make sure that the test cleans up its own directory BOTH before and after running, just in case it terminated partway through on the previous run of the test, and left some unwanted files lying around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mistake you have made is to mock `File`. There is a testing **anti pattern** that assumes that if your class delegates to class `X`, you **must** mock class `X` to test your class. There is also a general rule to be cautious of writing unit tests that do file I/O, because they tend to be too slow. But there is no absolute prohibition on file I/O in unit tests.

In your unit tests have a temporary directory set up and torn down, and create test files and directories within that temporary directory. Yes, your tests will be slower than pure CPU tests, but they will still be fast. JUnit even has support code to help with this very scenario: a `@Rule` on a `TemporaryFolder`.

Just this week I implemented, using TDD, some housekeeping code that had to scan through a directory and delete files, so I know this works.

Answer (score 1):

As someone who gets very antsy about unit tests that take longer than a few milliseconds to complete, I strongly recommend mocking out the file I/O.

However, I don't think you should mock the `File` class *directly*. Instead, look at your use of the `File` class as the "how", and try to identify the "what". Then [codify that with an interface](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/RoleInterface.html).

For example: you mentioned that one of the things you do is intercept calls to `File.isDirectory`. Instead of interacting with the `File` class, what if your code interacted with some implementation of an interface like:

```
public interface FileSystemNavigator {
    public boolean isDirectory(String path);

    // ... other relevant methods
}
```

This hides the use of `File.isDirectory` from the rest of your code, while simultaneously [reframing the problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reframing) into something more relevant to your program.