# Testing writing into a csv file using JUnit

Tags: java, junit, junit4, easymock

I am new to junit testing and I want to write unit tests. Actually the methods does not return anything. It take the a list of signals and write it to a csv file. I am not sure how to test methods with void return types.

Anyone can help me ?

```
public void createCSV ( final ArrayList< Signal > messages, File file )
{
    try
    {
        // Use FileWriter constructor that specifies open for appending
        csvOutput = new MyWriter( new FileWriter( file, false ), ',' );

        // Create Header for CSV
        csvOutput.writeRecord( "Message Source" );
        csvOutput.writeRecord( "Message Name" );
        csvOutput.writeRecord( "Component" );
        csvOutput.writeRecord( "Occurance" );
        csvOutput.writeRecord( "Message Payload with Header" );
        csvOutput.writeRecord( "Bandwidth(with Header %)" );
        csvOutput.writeRecord( "Message Payload" );
        csvOutput.writeRecord( "Bandwidth(%)" );
        csvOutput.endOfRecord();

        for ( Signal signal : messages )
        {
            csvOutput.writeRecord( signal.getSource() );
            csvOutput.writeRecord( signal.getName() );
            csvOutput.writeRecord( signal.getComponent() );
            csvOutput.writeRecord( Integer.toString( signal.getOccurance() ) );
            csvOutput.writeRecord( Integer.toString( signal
                .getSizewithHeader() ) );
            csvOutput.writeRecord( Float.toString( signal
                .getBandwidthWithHeader() ) );
            csvOutput.writeRecord( Integer.toString( signal.getSize() ) );
            csvOutput.writeRecord( Float.toString( signal.getBandwidth() ) );
            csvOutput.endOfRecord();
        }
    }
    catch ( IOException e )
    {
        logger.error( "Error in writing CSV file for messages", e );
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            if ( csvOutput != null )
            {
                csvOutput.flush();
                csvOutput.close();
            }
            messages.clear();
        }
        catch ( IOException ex )
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3381801/how-do-i-unit-test-saving-file-to-the-disk

Answer (score 3):

> One takes a map and sort it.

Pass in a map with known, unsorted values. Verify the map has been sorted after the method was called.

> The other take the sorted map and write it to a csv file. I am not sure how to test methods with void return types.

Two options:

1. Pass in a temporary file path, e.g. see [JUnit temporary folders](http://junit.org/javadoc/4.9/org/junit/rules/TemporaryFolder.html), then read that file after the method has been called and test it for correctness.
2. Adjust your method to accept an `OutputStream` instead of a `File`. Then you can pass a `ByteArrayOutputStream` and verify its contents by calling `toByteArray()` and inspecting the bytes.

Comment: Ok I created a map with unsorted values and I call the method passing that map how can I verify that the map is now sorted as the method does not return a sorted map

Comment: @UmairIqbal Either hand-craft a sorted map and compare the two or use an existing sort method that you trust (e.g. from JDK) to also sort the map and compare.

Comment: My question is I have two maps exactly with same content one is sorted and the other is unsorted I pass the unsorted map to the method which sorts the map. How can I compare both of them ? Do I need any assert statements? How?

Comment: @UmairIqbal What is the type of your map - `TreeMap`?

Comment: No it is simple Hashmap
private HashMap< String, Signal > _SignalsMap = new HashMap< String, Signal >();

Comment: @UmairIqbal A `HashMap` is not an ordered map,s o you can't sort it. You need a `TreeMap` to allow for sorting of keys.

Comment: I am using a SignalComparator Class which implements Comparator interface to sort my map based on the bandwidth value of each signal in the map

Comment: @UmairIqbal **You cannot sort a hash map**. If you have a `TreeMap` (or some other `SortedMap`), you can sort it by value (e.g. see [How to sort a Map<Key, Value> on the values in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2581754/474189)).

Comment: Why not I am doing it. I have a Hashmap ok, where the key is String and value is a signal Object. Initially the map is filled with values and then I pass this map to sort the entries according to the maximum bandwidth value of the signals... Signals with max bandwidth comes first and signals with min bandwidth comes last.

Comment: @UmairIqbal Oh, I've just looked properly at your code. So you are not sorting a map - you are taking the values from a map, sorting them into a list then outputting them to file. Very different. So your code will work fine, just ensure your test does the same sorting then verify the output looks correct.

Comment: How can I verify in JUnit testing that the list is sorted... this is my question

Comment: @UmairIqbal I think I've explained that already. In your test, you will also need to sort the list. Then compare the result your method produces with your own sorted list. Just use `assertEquals(yourSortedList, theListFromTheMethod);`.

Comment: The only thing I am confused about is How can I get theListFromTheMethod as the method does not return anything

Comment: @UmairIqbal Based on your current design, you'll need to read in the contents of the file produced and reconstruct the list. Probably better that you refactor your code and have a separate method that just sorts the map values. Then you can test it in isolation.

Answer (score 1):

**Unit test for File**

If you dont want to change the src code:

In the unit test I would pass a file to a temp path, call that create csv method and
then open the file and dependendent of how many effort you want to invest:

check
1) if the file exists (use a filename genereated that contains the current time)
2) check that the length is more than 0 bytes
3) read the first and last line and check for expected content

But in most cases, an `OutputStream` is more flexible than a `File` parameter.
In productive code you pass a `FileOutputStream`, in your unit test a `ByteArrayOutputStream`, which you can parse using an `ByteArrayInputStream`.

This is the cleaner solution, since it does not create files which should be cleaned up, and it runs faster.

**Unit test for sorting**
Just create an unsorted map. call you sort, and check the result to be sorted:
Iterate and check that each next element is e.g greater than the previous one (or smaller depending on the sort order)

Just